# Clear user input from JTextField with a DocumentFilter after JComboBox selection and keeping the placeholder text

Tags: java, swing

I'm having an issue. I can't really figure out how to properly clear user input from `JTextField` after a user makes a selection in a `JComboBox`. There's a `DocumentFilter` added to every `JTextField` for limiting max input length, so it kind of breaks the `setText("")` variant, because while `DocumentFilter` is set, it doesn't work. I worked around that by setting the `JTextField` to a `PlainDocument`, clearing the input and then re-adding the filter. Now the issue with this is that the placeholder text doesn't reappear until I don't click on the field. I'm using a `FocusListener` to add that prompt, so I understand why it appears again after clicking, but how can I make that placeholder text appears again after making a selection in `JComboBox`?

My `FocusListener`:

```java
public static class PlaceHolderText implements FocusListener {
    private final JTextField field;
    private final String placeHolder;
    private final Document defaultDocument;

    public PlaceHolderText(JTextField field, String placeHolder, Document defaultDocument) {
        this.field = field;
        this.placeHolder = placeHolder;
        this.defaultDocument = defaultDocument;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (field.getText().equals(placeHolder)){
            field.setDocument(defaultDocument);
            field.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
            field.setDocument(defaultDocument);
            field.setText(placeHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Clearing input:

```java
private void recreateTextFields() {
    titleField.setDocument(new PlainDocument());
    titleField.setText("");
    ((AbstractDocument)titleField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(inputLength);

    priceField.setDocument(new PlainDocument());
    priceField.setText("");
    ((AbstractDocument)priceField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(numericAndLengthPrice);

    pointsField.setDocument(new PlainDocument());
    pointsField.setText("");
    ((AbstractDocument)pointsField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(numericAndLengthPoints);
}
```

One of the selections in `JComboBox`:

```java
else if ("Property".equals(selectedItem)) {
    typeChosen = true;
    propertyCardChosen = true;
    if (cardInstanceCreated) {
        remove(cardInstance);
        cardInstanceCreated = false;
    }
    recreateTextFields();
    add(createCard(), "pos 950px 120px");
    revalidate();
    repaint();
```

I tried using [TextPrompt][1] library, but after clearing the input and when user enters something else, the prompt just stays behind the user input. And I thought about using *SwingX* library's `PromptSupport`, but as far as I know, *SwingX* isn't supported anymore.

MRE (including one of the DocumentFilters)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MRE extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pnlMenu;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MRE app = new MRE();
            }
        });
    }

    private MRE() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        create();
        add(pnlMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1600, 1000);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private JPanel create() {
        pnlMenu = new JPanel();
        String placeHolder = "PlaceHolder";
        JTextField field = new JTextField(placeHolder);
        Document defaultDocument = field.getDocument();
        field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (field.getText().equals(placeHolder)) {
                    field.setDocument(defaultDocument);
                    field.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    field.setText(placeHolder);
                }
            }
        });
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 40));
        ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericAndLengthFilter(2));
        String[] choicesString = { "1", "2" };
        JComboBox choices = new JComboBox(choicesString);
        choices.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    Object source = event.getSource();
                    if (source instanceof JComboBox) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox<String>) source;
                        Object selectedItem = cb.getSelectedItem();
                        if ("1".equals(selectedItem)) {
                            field.setDocument(defaultDocument);
                            field.setText("");
                            ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericAndLengthFilter(2));
                            revalidate();
                            repaint();
                        }
                        if ("2".equals(selectedItem)) {
                            field.setDocument(defaultDocument);
                            field.setText("");
                            ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericAndLengthFilter(2));
                            revalidate();
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        pnlMenu.add(field);
        pnlMenu.add(choices);
        return pnlMenu;
    }

    public static class NumericAndLengthFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        /**
         * Number of characters allowed.
         */
        private final int length;

        /**
         * Restricts the number of charcacters can be entered by given length.
         *
         * @param length Number of characters allowed.
         */
        public NumericAndLengthFilter(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (isNumeric(string)) {
                if (this.length > 0 && fb.getDocument().getLength() + string.length() > this.length) {
                    return;
                }
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (isNumeric(text)) {
                if (this.length > 0 && fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > this.length) {
                    return;
                }
                super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String text) {
        if (text == null || text.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < text.length(); iCount++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(iCount))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Even this implementation is buggy to be honest, not always does the place holder text disappear or even appears.

Comment: In order for me to help you fix your code, I need you to post a [mcve]. I don't understand how a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/generaltext.html#filter) can cause problems when calling method `setText("")`. The problem may be with your `DocumentFilter` implementation - which I didn't see in your question.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I tried using TextPrompt library_. Are you referring to this [TextPrompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/)?

Comment: 1) The TextPrompt class (referenced above) adds a DocumentListener to the Document of the text field. If you change the Document then you lose the functionality of the TextPrompt. So don't attempt to change the Document. 2)  *for limiting max input length,* - I agree with the above suggestion that the issue is with the implementation of the DocumentFilter. How does a length of 0 exceed the max length?

Comment: 3) I added the `TextPrompt` the the text pane in the `TextComponentDemo` example found in the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and it works fine.

Comment: I added an MRE with one of the documentFilters, hope it works. Well, I have a few DocumentFilters and it happens with every single one of them. I read somewhere, that the replace() method somehow changes how setText works? If I, for example, add at least a space into setText(" "), then it works, but that's not how I need it to work.

Comment: I would suggest you should NOT be attempting to keep changing the Document of the text field based on whether the "prompt" or the numeric digits are displayed. The TextPrompt was written so you don't need to manipulated the Document in this way.

Comment: *I tried reading Oracle's documentation about it, but it wasn't much of use for me* - not sure what you find confusing. The link above has a complete working example. Ask a specific question if there is something you don't understand. This issue is not the DocumentFilter. The issue is that you are using the text field incorrectly by attempting to update the Document with your prompt text. This will cause the DocumentFilter to be invoked with the invalid text. As a result you attempted to add a hack to prevent this which complicated the DocumentFilter usage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a problem when using the [TextPrompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class IntegerFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        replace(fb, offset, 0, text, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        //  In case someone tries to clear the Document by using setText(null)

        if (text == null)
            text = "";

        //  Build the text string assuming the replace of the text is successfull

        Document doc = fb.getDocument();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
        sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);

        if (validReplace(sb.toString()))
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attributes);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    private boolean validReplace(String text)
    {
        //  In case setText("") is used to clear the Document

        if (text.isEmpty())
            return true;

        //  Verify input is an Integer

        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt( text );
//          Double.parseDouble( text );
            return true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(4);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new IntegerFilter() );
        textField.setText("123");
//      textField.setText("123567");
//      textField.setText(null);
        TextPrompt tp = new TextPrompt("Enter Day:", textField);

        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        clear.addActionListener((e) -> textField.setText(""));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Integer Filter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(clear, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(220, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }

}
```

I'll let you modify the filter to limit the digits.

Comments on the DocumentFilter:

1. Note how the `insertString(...)` method invokes the `replace(...)` method. This is so you don't need to duplicate logic
2. The StringBuilder logic will allow you to properly test the length. You can't just add the length of the text in the Document with the length of the String to be added since you may have selected text in the text field which will be replaced by the new text. It also helps with validation of more complex text like numbers with decimal places.

Comment: Okey, thank you very much, I'll try out! But I was just wondering if there's any tutorial/material out there that would explain quite well DocumentFilter's usage? Because to be honest, for me it's quite hard to understand it. I tried reading Oracle's documentation about it, but it wasn't much of use for me.